# Declaration in MonoBehavior calling constructor and crashing

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In a MonoBehavior, I make a declaration of a custom object. This however leads to an error and a crash due to this error:

"UnityException: RandomRangeInt is not allowed to be called during serialization, call it from Awake or Start instead. Called from MonoBehaviour 'xxxxx' on game object 'xxx'."

RandomRangeInt is inside of the constructor of the object being declared, but it is not being instatiated there at all.  I am not sure why this is happening and an explanation would be lovely.

On another note, this problem goes away completely if I change the declaration to a static variable(var2 in the example code.

```
public class SampleClass: MonoBehaviour
{
    int var1;
    SampleClass2 var2;
}

public class SampleClass2
{
    int var1;

    public SampleClass2(){
    var1 = UnityEngine.Random.RandomRange(0,10);
    }
}
```

Comment: Creating an empty project with just a cube and `SampleClass` attached to it as a component compiles and runs without any errors, although there is a warning that `RandomRange` is obsolete and `Range` should be used instead. Please check your [mre].

Comment: You need to use `Start` or `Awake` on your first class that extends from monobehaviour, not inside the constructor of the second class.

Comment: Then were is it instantiated? The problem is: The default constructor is used for the serialization. Serialization happens in a lot of moments during runtime but also in the editor itself - at a moment when `Random.Range` doesn't work yet. We can't see where you instanciate this but you should rather do it like `var sample = new SampleClass2(); smaple.var1 = Random.RandomRange(0,10);` or alternatively pass it in as parameter and do `public SampleClass2(int value){ var1 = value;}` . Note that as soon as you have a specific constructor you also need a default one (can be empty though)